# Colorbox (jQuery) resize() not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9, colorbox

I'm using Colorbox version 1.3.19 with jQuery 1.7.2 on IE9. I have the following code to set up my Colorbox:

JS:

```
var colorbox_defaults =
{
    iframe           : true,
    title            : false,
    innerWidth       : 500,
    innerHeight      : 325,
    slideshow        : false,
    slideshowStart   : "",
    slideshowStop    : "",
    current          : "",
    previous         : "",
    next             : "",
    close            : ""
};

$( "#my_link" ).colorbox( colorbox_defaults );
```

HTML:

```
<a id="my_link" href="some_page.php">Click Here</a>
```

After all the content is loaded on the page, I have this code that resizes the colorbox based on the height of the content of the page (data is filled in via AJAX requests, so the page is variable in length), like so:

```
var options = { innerHeight : $( 'html' ).height() };
parent.$.fn.colorbox.resize( options );
```

This code works perfectly in both FF 12 and Chrome 18, but fails to resize in IE9. Any ideas why?

Comment: What does that call to `.height()` return? Sometimes IE says "auto" when the other browsers give a numeric amount. Have you tried putting a non-visible (but not hidden) element at the very bottom of the page and checking it's offset?

Comment: `console.log( $( 'html' ).height() );` is returning 500. No, I have not put a non-visible element at the bottom. I feel that should not be the proper solution to this issue.

Edit: Would you happen to know why IE9 is not returning the correct height while the other browsers are?

Comment: Couldn't tell you.  IE is IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I had to do to fix the problem. Apparently IE9 doesn't report the height of the html tag as other browsers such as FF and Chrome do. I had to select on the body tag, which reported the correct height.

My code changes to the following:

```
var options = { innerHeight : $( 'body' ).outerHeight( true ) };
parent.$.fn.colorbox.resize( options );
```